# join multiple rows from one table into one row from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables that look like this:
First:

> IdlokoStav,loko
>   12345,740 551-7

Second:

> idPersonalStav, personal, idLokostav
>   23456, Some Dude, 12345
>   23457, Another Dude, 12345

Result should look like:

> loko, Personal1, Personal2, personal3
>   740 551-7,Some Dude, Another Dude, NULL

There can be up to three people per one IdlokoStav, after I get this, I can join other things based on the result.
Db is Microsoft SQL 2008.

EDIT: I don´t care about how the people are ordered in the result as long as all three matches are included.

Comment: How do you know the sort order in the second table? Which one is first, second, third ?

Comment: There is always new idPersonalStav when the Dude is assigned to the loko. They can be assigned simultaniously. Since they get IdLokoStav when they are created, I think that should not be an issue?

Comment: So the sort order is determined by the `idPersonalStav` ?

Comment: yes, every new dude assigned to loko gets new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you don't want to put values into separate columns like this *for further processing in SQL*.  One method is to use `pivot`; another, conditional aggregation.  Both rely on the `row_number()` function:

```
select f.Idloko,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then s.personal end) as personal1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then s.personal end) as personal2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then s.personal end) as personal3
from first f left join
     (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by IdlokoStav order by idPersonalStav) as seqnum
      from second s
     ) s
     on f.IdlokoStav = s.IdlokoStav
group by f.Idloko;
```

If you discover that you have more than three names, then you'll need to add more `max()` statements in the outer `select`.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed I only needed to add the names of those max three people to the already finished query, no further joining required.